# This tag should be [blocked]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Related: [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

There is currently a [blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked) tag. Many of the questions are customer support "how do I get my account unblocked?" questions, which isn't even on topic here.

The tag is ambiguous, usually not on topic, and adds no useful information to posts. Can it be burninated?

As further proof that this ought to be burninated, the tag Wiki says

> This tag is ambiguous, please don't use it.

There you have it.

Comment: Or alternatively add a tag info page, and then do the usual thing with mistaggers?

Comment: (although yes, it's too broad, we need something like internet-connection-blocked, thread-blocked, etc.)

Comment: @user202729 "the usual thing"? Are you aware than other than total sublimation of the tag, nothing we have done is practically effective.

Comment: It just needs to go. Is 157 small enough of a tag to handle directly? Or do we need to close the off-topic questions first and then burninate the hell out of it?

Comment: @Luuklag going by 'Many of the questions are customer support "how do I get my account unblocked?" questions' I say it needs cleanup.

Comment: The tag should go IMO, it is way to ambiguous. As user202729 already stated, we need more topic-specififc tags.

Comment: I'd just rename the tag to 'blocking'.

Comment: @CarloWood How would that make the tag any less ambiguous? When would you use that tag?

Comment: @Luuklag The tag has attracted many off-topic questions.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I'm not sure what the current 'blocked' tag stands for, but when it has to do with coding then it is more appropriate to talk about 'blocking' (e.g. "In order to write a server using blocking I/O you'll need a thread per socket"). While 'blocked' is just an english word that isn't particularly useful to describe the method one is using. E.g "When I tried to write data to the socket, the function call blocked and froze the whole server. What can I do to fix this?"

Comment: @user202729 What's "the usual thing" to do with mistaggers? Give them a slap on the wrist? Lecture them? Suspend them indefinitely for abuse of the system?

Comment: @EJoshuaS (Braiam already point out that everything we do is pointless, including suspend indefinitely)

Answer (score 2):

Although "account blocked" issues are pretty off-topic here, we need to consider alternate meanings of "blocked" too.

One that I can think of is the UI thread getting blocked when running intensive code on it, for instance: *[Why Windows Forms UI is blocked when executing Task with ContinueWith?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48681248/1739000)*.

Comment: Yes, that's true - the fact that it could mean both is a problem, though.

Comment: That topic of thread blocking would be better served by [`ui-thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ui-thread/info) or even just [`multithreading`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/multithreading/info).

Comment: Or why not create [thread-blocking]? As most people will go close to block/blocking, adding thread to it might be just enough to make it clear.

Comment: Theres a continuewith tag already, why another?

Comment: @Braiam beg your pardon?

Comment: In the question you liked, there are 5 tags, one being [tag:continuewith] .

Comment: @Braiam s/liked/linked/ , and it is OK to have multiple tags (though it does look like they just threw their title into the tags box)...

Answer (score -4):

Here are a few topics which you might consider on topic for the site:

---

- *[Why is the Windows Forms UI blocked when executing Task with ContinueWith?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681248/why-windows-forms-ui-is-blocked-when-executing-task-with-continuewith)*
- *[Python request used to download the .csv file has been blocked, however, I could manually click it to download from the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182356/python-request-used-to-download-the-csv-file-has-been-blocked-however-i-could)*
- *[XAMPP: MySQL port blocked even when I changed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49336548/xampp-mysql-port-blocked-even-when-i-changed-it)*
- *[Iframe content blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686897/iframe-content-blocked)*
- *[Is there a way to find out that a user has opened a blocked popup in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999536/is-there-any-way-to-find-out-that-user-has-opened-blocked-popup-in-js)*
- *[Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - getting setup blocked error during installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795678/visual-studio-2015-update-3-getting-setup-blocked-error-while-installation)*

---

> What does **blocking** mean in programming languages?
>
> "Blocking" means that the caller waits until the callee finishes its processing. For instance, a "blocking read" from a socket waits until there is data to return; a "non-blocking" read does not, it just returns an indication (usually a count) of whether there was something read.
>
> You hear the term mostly around APIs that access resources that don't necessarily require CPU attention -- I/O, for instance. You also hear it in multi-threading: A call from Thread A to Thread B might be designed to "block" (hold up Thread A) until Thread B achieves the relevant state to process or at least accept the request. (The most obvious example there being "join", which usually means "I, Thread A, want to wait until Thread B has terminated" -- you use that when exiting a multi-threaded program.)
>   From :- [what-does-the-term-blocking-mean-in-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407589/what-does-the-term-blocking-mean-in-programming)

---

> Hope you have read "Criteria for burnination"

Before proposing burninating request you must read the criteria for burnination properly, [Here is a reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/9674579) and here are [4 criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   - Yes: 50%
   - No: 50%
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   - Yes: 50%
   - No: 50%
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   - Yes: 40%
   - No: 60%
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   - Yes: 70%
   - No: 30%

Comment: _Is it ambiguous_ -> _Yes: 50%, No: 50%_? _Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts_ -> _Yes: 70%, No: 30%_. Those things make absolutely no sense to me. Either a tag means the same thing in all common contexts, or it doesn't. And if it's ambiguous half the time, that kind of means it's ambiguous all the time.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth ~ `Either a tag means the same thing in all common contexts, or it doesn't. And if it's ambiguous half the time, that kind of means it's ambiguous all the time.` - it doesn't mean it's ambiguous all the time

Comment: It's not about the word, it's about the tag. A tag either has a clear, singular meaning, or it's ambiguous.

Comment: Webster's defines "ambiguous" as follows: "capable of being understood in two or more possible senses or ways." Either it can be understand in two or more possible senses or ways or it can't be; how can it be 50% ambiguous and 50% unambiguous? If it's 50% ambiguous, wouldn't that mean that there are multiple ways of interpreting it, and that it's therefore 100% ambiguous?